# Converting a stack to a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, stack

I'm trying to convert a stack into a string. The function I have is

```
int StackToString(const struct Stack *stack, char *result, int resultSize);
```

I want my stack to look like

- stack[STACK_MEMORY_ADDRESS]:
- ELEMENT_NUMBER:DATA
  ...
- ELEMENT_NUMBER:DATA

If there is enough space in the result, the string should be stored there and I want to return with a "1" value. If there isn't (dictated by resultSize) then we return 0 and the result is undefined.

So far, this is what I have written:

```
int StackToString(const struct Stack *stack, char *result, int resultSize){
    int i;
    char str[20];
    sprintf(str, "stack[0x%x]:\n", stack);
    strcat(result, str);
    for(i=0; i<stack->currentItemIndex;i++){
    ???
}
}
```

Can anyone offer any advice on what I should do next? I think I need to do a sprint with something and compare the remaining elements in the stack to the resultsize and return under certain but I'm not sure how to implement it....

Comment: `sprintf` into str and `strcat` to result, as you already are doing, just in a loop? That sounds like the right idea.

Comment: What kind of data you keep in `stack`?

Comment: Are you allowed to destroy the stack?  Does the stack provide access to the interior elements?  If not, you are likely to need to pop items off one stack, convert them to string, and push the item onto another stack.  When the original stack is empty, you can reload with items popped of the second stack — the ordering works out fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` you can get rid of the intermediate buffer and extra copying. Also this would guarantee that your result buffer will not be overwritten.

```
int StackToString(const struct Stack *stack, char *result, int resultSize) {
    int i;
    int n;
    n = snprintf(result, resultSize, "stack[0x%x]:\n", stack);
    if (n < 0 || n >= resultSize)
        return 0;
    result += n;
    resultSize -= n;
    for (i = 0; i < stack->currentItemIndex; i++) {
        n = snprintf(result, resultSize, "%d: 0x%x\n", i, stack->items[i]);
        if (n < 0 || n >= resultSize)
            return 0;
        result += n;
        resultSize -= n;
    }
    return 1;
}
```